# Does the inclusion of "bien" make a question a non-question?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique

> Mais au fait, y en avait **bien** un autre avec vous ?
>
> {vs} Mais au fait, y en avait un autre avec vous ?

I wonder if the use of "bien" makes it a statement, something along the lines of:

> Moi qui pensais qu’il y en avait un autre avec vous. Il s'est passé quoi, au juste ?

Can you think of some other examples like this?

Comment: Yes, *bien* suggests that you're seeking confirmation of a fact you have heard stated or alluded to previously. "Was there really? Was there in fact?" Synonyms such as *vraiment* will indeed have a similar effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is right on this context. You could have say:

> C'est bien ça?

I would have answered

> C'est bien ça!

It means you were pretty sure to be right, but ask for confirmation.
Another example:

> Avez-vous bien renvoyé le formulaire comme demandé?

We use that to insist on the fact you should know that statement, but ask just for confirmation.

Use of *bien* is not only for questions, it works the same way in statement. Both means that we are almost 100% sure of it:

> J'ai bien renvoyé le formulaire comme demandé.